Compose: Adding clip modifier makes unit tests fail
I have a composable with unit tests. When I add the clip modifier to it to clip the background to a particular shape, the unit tests verify click behavior starts to fail.
If I use default compose shape RoundCornerShape or CircleShape for the clip the tests pass, only when I use a custom shape (using Outline.Generic) the tests start failing.
// Layout
MyView.clip().background().border().padding().clickable().testTag("CONTAINER_TAG")

// Test
composeRule.onNodeWithTag("CONTAINER_TAG", true).performClick() // Fail only when clip modifier with custom shape is added.


clip().background().border().padding().clickable() 

All this modifiers require values. For example:
.clip(shape: Shape) 
.background(color: Color)

Or, if your code has this, can you provide mode code for understanding your problem ?

It's obvious that the modifier parameters are present, otherwise the app wouldn't even compile. If you want to ask for clarification instead please do that in a comment, not in an answer. Answers should actually answer the question, which your answer does not.
